# Build Status in Github

Tags: testing, github, build

Whenever I clone a repository, I see on the GithHub page a certain icon indicating the **build** - for example *build passing*.

I am extremely new to professional code development. I would really appreciate it if someone could tell me what a particular build status indicates ? Brief answers would do !

Comment: Could you give concrete examples that you don't understand? Or ae you asking what "build" means?

Comment: @JB Nizet - ok for example here - https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit - It says **build : passing**. I searched a lot but could not find a good explanation as to what a build status means !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Software projects consist in a set of source files, and of an automated procedure used to "build" the executable product or library. This procedure is called "the build". It can fail for various reasons:

- compilation error
- automated tests failing
- coding conventions not respected
- bug in the build script
- etc.

"Build passing" indicates that the build procedure completed successfully. "Build failed" indicates that the build procedure failed.

Usually, this build procedure is executed automatically each time a new commit is made on the repository. A continuous integration server like Travis or Jenkins downloads the project for the last commit, then launches the build, checks that it succeeds, and updates the build status.

Comment: Coding conventions ? Isn't that too strict to hamper a build ?

Comment: It all depends on the level of quality and coherence you want to enforce. Some projests don't have any check, some have checks, but only emit a report containing the warnings without failing the build, and some make the build fail as soon as a rule with a given severity level is broken. Making the build fail allows detecting and fixing the problem ASAP. It also helps forcing external contributors to comply.

Comment: Nevertheless, you just saved the day ! I was beginning to feel the question would go down as another tumbleweed. Thanks !